# C++ Setting a TDateTime variable

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I am having trouble setting the date to a TDateTime variable.

I have tried this, with no luck:

```
TDateTime Mine;
Mine = ("12/05/1990");
```

How can I do this?

---

What is wrong with this code:

```
TDateTime Mine("05/05/1990",Date);
```

I am getting the following error:

[BCC32 Error] File1.cpp(28): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TDateTime::TDateTime(const char *,TDateTime (_fastcall *)())'
  Full parser context
    File1.cpp(26): parsing: int main(int,char * *)

Comment: I assume you are talking about [TDateTime](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!OVERLOADED_TDateTime_System__TDateTime.html). Please specify what C++ library you are using in the future.

Comment: Try TDateTime(year,month,day);

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you are trying to call constructor on second line.

```
TDateTime Mine("12/05/1990",TDateTime::Date); // construction
// some code using Mine
Mine = TDateTime("13/05/1990",TDateTime::Date); // assignment
```

If you want to have only single argument of constructor then you should have also the time in that string like `TDateTime("12/05/1990 12:00 am")`.

Comment: Thanks. Next TDateTime question. If I have a TDateTime value, how can I do date arithmetic on it. By that I mean, if I have a two TDateTime variables, how can I calculate the time difference between them and format this value as mnth::dd:hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek That's complicated, because "one month" isn't representable as a fixed number of days. But you can subtract two `DateTimes` which will give you a useful result if you only look at the result's time and number of days (so 1 Feb - 1 Jan = 31 days, not 1 month) (Edit: that's assuming you're not dealing with any datetimes before `TDateTime(0)`.)

Comment: I am using this code: TDateTime Mine("12/05/1990",Date); and am getting this error: E2285 Could not find a match for 'TDateTime::TDateTime(const char *,TDateTime (_fastcall *)())'

Comment: @JesseGood: 'TDateTimeFlag' is not a class or namespace name... :(

Comment: It should be TDateTime::Date? enums do not form name scope, unless i misunderstand something.

Comment: @JesseGood: Now I am getting multiple [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall errors...

Comment: Can someone please test out a simple one line statement to get a simple TDateTime variable working... Not sure why I am finding it so hard...

Comment: Linker errors indicate that you do not link needed libraries, or forgot to define some declared function/variable/member function/static data member it is orthogonal to your original problem.

Comment: @DarrylJanecek: Then the problem is not with the code (the code is correct), those are linker errors, so you need to make sure your library paths are correct, etc. I cannot help any further.

Comment: @JesseGood: I have a new installation of C++ Builder. I have included #include <vcl.h> (and others). Where can I get some advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek: [See here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Helpful_Resources_for_New_Users#C.2B.2BBuilder_Programming) and read the pdf `Introduction to C++Builder 2010` which should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: OK, I think I need to add vcle.lib to the linker settings. I am not sure where they are though.

Comment: OK, I think I have it working... no compile errors. Just to make sure, how can I print the status of the: TDateTime Mine("12/05/1990")?